# Can not receive the post request

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx

I can`t receive the post request from html form submit, the detail is as below:

A very simple html page:

```
<form name="redirectpost" method="post" action='http://xxx.chxxxxxxt.com/oauth>


        <input type="hidden" name="data" value="132">

        <input type="submit">

</form>
```

And, on the server side, I use the jfinal framework:

```
@Before(OauthInterceptor.class)
public class OauthController extends BaseController<Oauth> {
    public void index() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        HttpServletRequest request = this.getRequest();
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String data1 = request.getParameter("data");
        System.out.println(data1);
        ......
}
```

I always receive null for "data". But I can revevie data if I change the form method to 'Get'.

What`s more, on my server, I receive all the requests by Nginx, then posts the requests to tomcat according to the reqeust host name:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxx.chxxxxxxt.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8091;
    }
  }
```

The tomcat version is 7.0.59, Thanks for help!

ps:

Actually, when I test those code on another server run by jetty, everything is right! So, I think the problem is caused by tomcat.

Comment: How are you retrieving param in getPara??

Comment: @JunedAhsan  I removed that, problem remains.

Comment: `request.getParameter("data")` probably will work

Comment: @JunedAhsan  It is a method provided by parent class 'BaseController' of jfinal framework. I think it is not the problem of this method. Actually, when I test those code on another server run by jetty, everything is right!  So, I think the problem is caused by tomcat.